# Symfony2 @Assert\Date() controller validation

Tags: php, symfony, date, format

I have some easy code for entity User in my project

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
protected $dateOfBirth;
```

As written on [Official Documentation for Date()](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/Date.html) i can send Date parameters like "YYYY-MM-DD", but i always get errors after submit in controller

```
$form = $this->createForm('Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\UserType', new User(), array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```

Response:

```
"dateOfBirth": {
            "errors": [
                "This value is not valid."
            ],
            "children": {
                "year": {},
                "month": {},
                "day": {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you do a `dump($request->request->all()['dateOfBirth'])` ?

Comment: UserController.php on line 49:
"1992-01-01"

Comment: can you add UserType code